# how to split a dataframe to form a multiple dataframe in a single context in django python

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

> How can i split by big dataframe into smaller dataframe and able to print all the dataframe separately on web? any idea on edit code can place a loop in context?
>   here is my code:
>
> ```
> def read_raw_data(request):
>      Wb = pd.read_excel(r"LookAhead.xlsm", sheetname="Step")
>      Step1 = Wb.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
>      drop_column = 
>      Step1_Result.drop(['facility','volume','indicator_product'], 1)
>      uniquevaluesproduct = np.unique(drop_column[['Product']].values)
>      total_count=drop_column['Product'].nunique()
>      row_array=[]
>      for name, group in drop_column.groupby('Product')
>             group=group.values.tolist()
>             row_array.append(group)
>      i=1
>      temp=row_array[0]
>      while i<total_count:
>            newb = temp + row_array[i]
>            temp=newb
>            i = i + 1
>     b = ['indicator', 'Product']
>     test=pd.DataFrame.from_records(temp, columns=b)
>     table = test.style.set_table_attributes('border="" class = "dataframe table table-hover table-bordered"').set_precision(10).render()
>     context = { "result": table}
>     return render(request, 'result.html', context)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a big dataframe in different pages, I recommend you using a `Paginator`. The documentation has a good example on how to implement it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view

Comment: hi, i need to separate the dataframe in to smaller dataframe base on hw many product, then each of the dataframe appear in different page, any idea on how to print out all in one context "result" or any looping can happen in context?. and there is possible to create html button in py file? because the number of the button is base on the number of Product so i plan to used loop function to create the button is it possible?